# Is there any way to get array of child association ids while using 'include' option to query in 'Sequelize'?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model called A, and it has many B. when I query A from mysql, I want to have something like this

```
{ a: { b_ids: [1, 2, 3] } }
```

my current code looks like this:

```
A.findOne({
    where: {id: id},
    include: [
      {
        model: B,
        attributes: [
          'id'
        ]
      }
})
```

and i get { a: { bs: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}] } }, is there any way that I can return an array of child association ids instead of an array of object?

Comment: Why don't you just run ```map``` on *bs* by ids?

Comment: because what sequelize return from findOne is not just a simple object like what I typed above, it is way more complex than it, i simplified it just because it is easy to understand. for example, the bs part in reality is a : { datavalues: { bs: { datavalues: [{ id..........}]}}. I could totally do it, but only if there is no better way